# Functions and partial orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I have the following statement to prove but not sure how to get started :

Let ***f: A → B*** and ***g: B → A*** be arbitrary functions.
Show that there are subsets A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub> ⊆ A and B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub> ⊆ B such that : A<sub>1</sub> ∪ A<sub>2</sub> = A, A<sub>1</sub> ∩ A<sub>2</sub> = ∅ and B<sub>1</sub> ∪ B<sub>2</sub> = B, B<sub>1</sub> ∩ B<sub>2</sub> = ∅ and f(A<sub>1</sub>) = B<sub>1</sub>, g(B<sub>2</sub>) = A<sub>2</sub>.

I believe we need to use the notion of partial order here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why did you say $g(A_2)$ when $g$ is not defined on $A$?

Comment: My bad ! Let me edit this !